# C# Webservice stucks. Need to override published file to restart

Tags: c#, web-services, transactions

Please help me, I'm facing a fatal problem here. If someone could fix this, I swear I will treat u to a huge drink whenever u step into my country (Vietnam). Ok here's the problem: I'm coding a webservice for multi connection simultaneously from tablet (around 100 clients). It ran well but recently whenever high traffic occurs, my webservice seems to stuck somehow and I need to copy - override the published file of webservice in order for it to run again (restart website in IIS is no use) ...

This is my w/s code for handling the data:

```
public string Info_Handling(string id, string name, string strDetails)
{
    string checkExist = "";
    string str = "";
    string str2 = "";

    MLL_Customer _customerClient = new MLL_Customer();
    MLL_CustomerCategory _categoryClient = new MLL_CustomerCategory();
    MLL_Product _productClient = new MLL_Product();
    MLL_SampleProduct _sampleClient = new MLL_SampleProduct();

    if (_customerClient.CheckExistCustomer(id, name.ToUpper(), 2) == 1) // SID & NAME
    {
        checkExist = "EXIST";
    }

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Main.ConnectionString"]))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction("XXX");
        try
        {
            // ID Example: 11 means VIP - 12 means Normal - 13 means ples... jkg
            // First - Insert Customer
            string strCustomerCategory = _categoryClient.SelectCategoryByID(id).ToString();

            if (!checkExist.Equals("EXIST"))
            {
                Customer businessObject = new Customer();
                businessObject.ID = sid;
                businessObject.Name = name.ToUpper();
                businessObject.CategoryID = strCustomerCategory;
                str = "" + _customerClient.Insert(businessObject, connection, trans);
            }

            // Second Insert Product spliting from a string Ex: "TV&Laptop&CD"
            string[] productDetails = strDetails.Split(new char[] { '&' });                                                  
            object obj3;
            SampleProduct objSample;
            Product objProduct;

            for (int j = 0; j < productDetails.Length; j++)
            {
                if (_productClient.CheckExist(id, productDetails[j])) == null) // Check if customer already owns this product
                {
                    // Get the properties of sample product.
                    objSample = _sampleClient.SelectSampleProduct(productDetails[j]);
                    objProduct = new Product();
                    objProduct.SID = sid;
                    objProduct.Testcode = objSample.TestCode;
                    objProduct.Category = objSample.Category;
                    objProduct.Unit = objSample.Unit;
                    objProduct.Price = objSample.Price;

                    if (_productClient.Insert(objProduct, connection, trans) != 0)
                    {
                        str2 = str2 + "&" + objProduct.Testcode;
                        // return the code of product in order to see which product has been inserted successfully
                    }
                }
            }
            trans.Commit();
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools(); 

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            str = "0";
            str2 = exception.Message + exception.Source;
            try
            {
                trans.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    if (!str2.Equals(""))
    {
        return (str + "&" + id + str2);
    }

    return ("0&" + sid + str);
}
```

I modified the code but this is basically how i roll. Could anyone plz tell me some solution. Deeply thank u.

- 1 more thing about ClearAllPools() method: I know how it works but I dont even know why I need it. Without this, my data will be messed up terrible. CategoryID of one customer will be assigned for another customer sometimes. ????  How could it happened ?? HELP

Comment: If your productClient makes a select from DB you may be executing too many in the for loop in a transaction which is not good. Also, clear all pools is the worst because it will cause new connections to be opened to the DB instead of reusing them. First of all, get rid of that. Second, you should only execute minimal number of and only atomic operations when you begin a transaction. Do not execute select statements in a transaction, this can cause a dead lock.

Comment: Do productClient and sampleClient select from DB?

Comment: Also, next time you can get a dump of the process when it is stuck and I will be happy to analyze it and to tell you the reason of the hang.

Comment: Oguz Gzgul: Thank you for reply sir. I'm trying to think of a way to not exec this much Select statement in a transaction... Is it OK if I combine CheckExist and Insert into a procedure ?

Comment: ..and yes, productClient and sampleClient  also select from DB!

Comment: Yes, you can combine all the select and insert statements into a single sp and begin tran in the sp. instead of for each statement achieve the same by a not in SQL operator

Comment: And please don't call me sir we will have that drink together later

Comment: Ok bro. I will try fixing this w/s as u said. Could u kindly give me your email so that we can discuss later and I could know the time to prepare our drink.